# Element is Null when using @AndroidFindBy

Tags: java, cross-browser, appium

I am working on a cross platform scripting and I am using the page object model. I am using @AndroidFindBy(id = "")/ @iosFindBy("") annotations to identify the elements. I m unable to run my scripts as I m getting a null pointer exception.

I debugged and found that the element is Null. (please refer to the screenshot)
[image]

I have already initialised my driver when initialising the desiredCapabilities. but I m not sure how to look for the element in the driver.

```
driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(url, desiredCapabilities);
```

The code works fine when I m only using AndroidDriver and use ,

```
driver.findElement(By.id(""))
```

But it fails when I m trying to run with @AndroidFindBy(id=""). Where do I mention about where the element should be looked in for? Any headsup or guidance would be appreciated

Comment: How are you instantiating the class?  Are you using the pagefactory?  Where is the code that references the POM?

Comment: hi @BillHileman , I m using the pagefactory .Im creating the elements in the Page.java class, and creating the object of that class in PageTest.java. I am initialising the elements, `PageFactory.initElements(driver, BaseTest.class);` in BaseTest class where I initialising the desiredCapabilities and the driver.

Answer (score 3):

I create a main page object class which contains the class instantiation, then each page object class I create implements that base page object class shown below:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator;

public class PageObject {

    AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;

    public PageObject(AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver) {

        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS), this);

    }

}
```

Your problem might be as simple as the class parameter you are passing is hard-coded, possibly to the wrong class.  It should be the page object's class itself, hence "this"

Here's a segment of a page class that extends the page object above:

```
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AndroidFindBy;

public class CalculatorPage extends PageObject {

    public CalculatorPage(AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver) {
        super(driver);
        System.out.println("Calculator page class has been initialized");
    }

    @AndroidFindBy(id = "com.android.calculator2:id/formula")
    AndroidElement formula;
    @AndroidFindBy(id = "com.android.calculator2:id/result")
    AndroidElement result;

    public String getResult() {
        String text = helper.getText(result, "Result");
        if ("".equals(text)) 
            text = helper.getText(formula, "Formula");
        return text;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @BillHileman when I add this line of code I get another error                                     
`public class LaunchPage {
 AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;

 public LaunchPage(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
  this.driver = driver;
 PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver, 30,
    TimeUnit.SECONDS), this);
   }`

Comment: org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class tests.LaunchPageTest
 at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator.getTypeForProxy(AppiumFieldDecorator.java:233)
 at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator.proxyForAnElement(AppiumFieldDecorator.java:248)

Comment: I just re-looked at your original screen shot and noticed that your element definitions are not quite right for this setup.  I'll have to post a code example in the morning (I'm at home now) to show where I think your problem might now be.

Comment: I've added a segment of my page object to the original answer.  Hope this answers/helps.

Comment: I tried it but still I get a null pointer in the line, in BasePage
`PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS), this);`

Comment: Double-check your imports - it may have imported the wrong pagefactory.  Note that my example uses the selenium version, not the appium or android version.